# how to web scraping to get information from mvnrepository.com artifact page, status code 403

Tags: python-requests, mvn-repo

https://mvnrepository.com gives information about an artifact such as *License*, *Repository(Central, Atlassian etc)*, *Category* etc.

Also, in an artifact page, there is information for versions like  *Vulnerability*,*Date* etc.

I would like to parse the *license, Repository* for some packages and *vulnerability* for their versions.

Here is an example: from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api, I want:

```
{"groupID".:"org.junit.jupiter",

 "artifactID":"junit-jupiter-api",

 "License": "EPL 2.0",

 "Vuln": {},

 "latestVersion": {"5.9.0":"Jun 26, 2022"}}
```

I'm using

```
import requests

url = 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api'
result = requests.get(url)
result
```

getting

```
<Response [403]>
```

I have tried adding headers, but no changes.

```
header = {
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Cookie': '*********from browser DevTools*********',
    'Referer':'https://mvnrepository.com/',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua':'.Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile':'?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform':"macOS",
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1'
}
result = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
result
>>> <Response [403]>
```

Comment: Web scraping is normally frowned upon. Have you considered using https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide/ ?

Comment: @SiKing, Thank you for the suggestion! Yes. I do consider using this for the artifacts in the central repo. But the artifacts in other repositories are not searchable in this api, aren't they?

Comment: mvnrepository is not a repository, but a search engine. And, as you discovered, it probably does not allow web scraping.

Answer (score -1):

Try
result = requests.get(url.text)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?